# Parameter type of method to correspond to inner class which extends super's inner class

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have some classes structured as follows:

```
class A {
    inner class B {}

    void func(B param) {}
}

class Asub extends A {
    inner class B extends A.B {}

    @Override
    void func(B param) {}      // problematic line
}
```

But the compiler doesn't allow it as a proper override and only allows it if I change (in `Asub`)

`void func(B param)`

to

`void func(A.B param)`

However I do not want to do that as I have some overriden functionality defined in `Asub.B` that I want to make use of but if I change the `param` type to `A.B` instead of `B`, the linter tells me that `Asub.B` is unused

I would appreciate any help in solving this issue or if it is not possible, a possible alternate approach to accomplish the functionality that I want

The actual context of this question has to do with Android `RecyclerView.Adapter`s and `ViewHolder`s but I don't think the problem resides there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your best shot here is using generics.

Something along the lines of

```
abstract class A<T extends A.B> {
    class B {
      // ...
    }

    abstract void func(T param) {
      //..
    }
}

class Asub<Asub.B> extends A {
    class B extends A.B {
      // ...
    }


    @Override
    void func(Asub.B param) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

should probably do the job.

Comment: thanks, I believe this is similar to how Android's default RecyclerView Adapter and ViewHolder themselves are structured so it's probably my best bet

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with inner classes, the problem here is that you cannot override a function f(A) with f(B extends A), because all overridden methods have to be able to accept all parameter that would be allowed for the super method.

You can of course always cast to the subtype in the overriding method.

Comment: Thank you, it's starting to make sense. Unfortunately I cannot do that as the method is a required method that is called from Android internally

Answer (score 2):

What language is this question for exactly? `extends`, `void`, and `@Override` are Java, while `inner class`is Kotlin.

---

Aside from that, it doesn't make sense to override a function and then restrict what it can take as its parameter. What do you expect to happen when someone does this?

```
A asub = new Asub();
asub.func(new A.B());
```

If you got what you wanted, this function call would no longer be valid - this is breaking the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), which basically prescribes "**expect no more**, provide no less". And thankfully, neither Java or Kotlin will allow this.

Comment: sorry, i've been programming in kotlin but thinking in java so i kinda just wrote a mix of the two

Comment: i'm trying to structure it so that the current A class uses it's corresponding B class both of which get the benefits of the boilerplate code from their superclasses

Comment: But I do see your point about not allowing subtyping in parameters